# I want to fetch data from a column on a database, average the data received, and echo the result

Tags: php, mysqli

I have created a database called quizresults. Within it there are two columns; id and result. So far I have the code below;

```
$average = "SELECT result FROM quizresults;";
$averageresult = mysqli_query($conn, $average);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($averageresult);

if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($averageresult)) {
        echo $row[]
    }
}
```

Im not 100% sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First: `echo $row['result'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array with all the results from the query, take the sum of it and divide it by the amount of elements in the array.

```
$array = [];

if($resultcheck > 0) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($averageresult)) {
        array_push($array, $row['result']);
    }

}

// Calculate average
$average = array_sum($array) / count($array);

// Format it to 2 decimals
$average = number_format($average, 2);

// Echo it
echo $average;
```

Comment: Its still displaying the same. I think it could be a problem within my echo statement?      echo '<br><p>The average result out of 10 is </p>$average';

Comment: You need double qoutes, otherwise it won't echo the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Just will leave it here
`SELECT AVG(result) AS AverageResult FROM quizresults;`

Mysql builtin function avg